# Não entendo e não sei onde encontrar essa informaçãor

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let transactionSchema = new Schema({
  userId: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  transactionDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  transactionType: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  charge: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  deposit: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  notes: { type: String, default: '' },
  createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

const Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema)

module.exports = Transaction
```

No codigo acima entendo que estou trabalhando na parte de modelo pois tenho conhecimento de MVC percebo que estou monstando minha base de dados e ETC mas oque eu nao percebo é este trecho:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

Ele cria uma constante ok mas como funciona esse require ? Ate onde percebi ele deveria buscar da minha pasta node_modules os arquivos que ele precisa para executar correto ? mas como isso funciona exatamente? sabem de alguma documentação disso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser esse nível de detalhe, melhor ver o código fonte: [module.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L354)

E aqui a documentação em inglês: [node require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id)

Mas simplificando, se informar apenas o nome do módulo como no seu exemplo, o `require` vai  procurar pelo módulo em todas as pastas configurados no *module.paths*, ou pode passar o caminho onde está o módulo, assim:  `require('/meus-modulos/mongoose')`;